# Incorrect ruby version when installing bundle in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, sharetribe

I have a problem when running `bundle install` in the root of sharetribe rails's project. It shows me this error message:

> Your Ruby version is 2.4.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1

I tried installing rvm and installing the 2.3.1 version required to run this project but nothing changes and it still throwing this output.

Have anyone faced this problem before ?

Comment: In rbenv you would need to set the "local" version of ruby to be 2.3.1 for a particular project folder (while your global version would still be 2.4.0), not sure it's the same with rvm, but probably you need to tell it to use 2.3.1 in that particular project?

Comment: Did you try `rvm use 2.3.1`?

Comment: @SaketramDurbha, yeah I forget to run the "rvm use ruby-2.3.1" in the root folder and that was my mistake. Thnx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your Ruby version is 2.4.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1

Steps to resolve this issue

```
1)rvm install ruby-2.3.1

2)gem install bundler

3)rvm use ruby-2.3.1

4)Bundle install
```

Comment: This worked for me but i have to rerun the 2nd command after the "rvm use ruby-2.3.1" command to fix it because the order you gave me isn't efficient for my case and i didn't know the reason .
Thnx a lot .

Answer (score 1):

> Your Ruby version is 2.4.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1

If you run command `ruby -v` you can see that you have installed `Ruby 2.4.0`, when you look at the first line in your Gemfile specifies that you want to use `Ruby 2.3.1`.

You can do either install `Ruby 2.3.1` or replace the first line in your Gemfile to with `Ruby 2.4.0`.

Comment: Replacing the ruby version from the Gemfile didn't fix the problem. I have to install the 2.3.1 ruby version using the rvm and than use it in my project root folder. 
Thnx for your answer.

Comment: @YasserKotrsi ofcourse , Replacing the ruby version is fix the problem if your ruby version is nearest to your install version one, and yes I will give you possible fo solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What does it say when you run `bundle env` in the terminal?

Is it the same ruby version?

I tried `gem install bundler` one time i had the same problem and bundle updated and worked.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4260).

Good luck!